# Shrinking Menu with unwelcome moves of links when clicked

Tags: css, navbar

I coded a navbar that shrinks when we scroll down and go back to normal size when we scroll back to the top.
It works ok.
Everypage of the site has the same navbar.
But when we click on one item of the menu to go on one specific page, there is an unwelcome move of the links of the menu.
I tried to use other shrinking navbar found on codepen, aNd theY suffer from the same problem. I added other pages and real achors to this code, and the same problem occurred.
Can someone help me?
Thanks!

I tried different codepen codes with the same problematic result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.